# is it possible to compile android .java source files produced jd-gui

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, smali, dex2jar

I want to change some lines in smali file.
I converted android's classes.dex to classes.jar by using dex2jar. then used jd-gui to see source files and saved them . from this I got .java files . after editing I want to recompile them to see the differences in resulting smali by recompiling it , convert jar to dex , atlast redecompile it see differences in smali
is this possible?

I want to do like this because source code is easy to understand and doing edits than editing smali

Comment: If you just want to change stuff directly in the smali files, there's no need to mess around with dex2jar or jd-gui. Just modify the smali files directly and reassemble with smali.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below. Only thing to point out when I copied and pasted the command lines, I got an error. I just retyped the commands and it worked.

http://adrynalyne-teachtofish.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-decompile-and-recompile-jar.html

or an even more detailed version

http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/wiki/ModifyApkWithDexTool